# Zooming in and out on a 2D plot

Tags: plotting

I made a simple 2D plot, but I can't zoom in-out on the figure. I tried many ways. But none gave any results.

> Click anywhere + drag the mouse zooms in/out on the point where the mouse was clicked.
>   Ctrl + drag toggles zooming rectangle (from Szabolcs).
>   Shift + drag pans the plot (from Heike).
>   Alt shows coordinates (only when over the plot so that other global Alt-functionality (like Alt+C+L to remove output) can be still used). *)
>   Double click anywhere resets the plot (from kguler).
>   Resize handler at bottom right corner to manipulate ImageSize (does not change aspect ratio).
>   Ctrl + resize also changes aspect ratio.".

I attach a picture shows that it is impossible to zoom in and out.

[image].

Comment: You could use PlotRange to choose what part of the image you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

The graphics interactions you quote only apply to 3D plots. 2D plot's do not have such support built-in. But do not dispair, Heike's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7012/3066) can easily be adapted to your list plot.

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = Accumulate /@ RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {3, 250}];
DynamicModule[{range, ref, range0, fac = 2/3},
  range = range0 = {{0, 250}, MinMax[data]};
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic @
      ListLinePlot[data,
        PlotRange -> range,
        Filling -> Axis,
        ImageSize -> Large],
   {"MouseDown" :> 
     (ref = MousePosition["GraphicsImageScaled"]; 
      range0 = range), 
    "MouseDragged" :> 
      (* pan *)
      (range = 
        range0 + 
          (ref - MousePosition["GraphicsImageScaled"]) 
            (range0[[All, 2]] - range0[[All, 1]])),
    "MouseClicked" :>
      Which[
        (* zoom in *)
        CurrentValue["AltKey"], (* Cmnd on OS X *)
        range = 
          (range - MousePosition["Graphics"])*fac + MousePosition["Graphics"], 
        (* zoom out *)
        CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], 
        range = 
          (range - MousePosition["Graphics"])/fac + MousePosition["Graphics"]]}]]
```

When first evaluated it looks like this.

[image: plot]

After paning and zooming it can look like this.

[image: zoomed]