# How to make a custom DynamicImage which support mouse wheel and show pixel value?

Tags: image-processing, magnification

The built-in `DynamicImage` just click the plus sign or minus sign to rescale the image. I have to say click is a not very good operation. Could we make the custom `DynamicImage` which support the mouse wheel to rescale the image, and I hope it will show the **pixel value** when the image is large enough. I have recorded a gif for what I want.

[image]

It is a useful tool for debugging. But I don't know how to implement it in *Mathematica*

Comment: I don't think `EventHandler` has access to any mouse-wheel actions. That's the main reason this won't work. You could always do a control-mouse drag though, like `Graphics3D`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Or we can use click action to magnify image and `ctrl+click` to shrink image.

Comment: Another idea is to click + drag to zoom in to the rectangle defined by the starting and stopping points.

Comment: @ChipHurst Then you have you draw a rectangle every time to zoom.

Answer (score 6):

A few simple tweaks of @Heike's [answer to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7012/want-interactive-plotrange-of-graphics) gets you most of the way there.

```
ImageZoom[img_Image] := 
    DynamicModule[{range,range0,range1,ref,ref2,fac=.7,z=.9,dim,y,aspect,xaspect=1},
        dim = ImageDimensions@img;
        aspect = 1.*Divide@@dim;
        If[aspect>1, xaspect = aspect];
        range = range0 = {{0,xaspect}, {0,1}};
        EventHandler[Graphics[{Inset[Image[img], {0,0}, {0,0}, aspect]},
                    PlotRange->Dynamic[range], ImageSize->500],{
            "MouseDown" :> (ref=MousePosition["GraphicsImageScaled"];
                        range0=range;ref2=MousePosition["Graphics"];),
            "MouseDragged" :> Which[
                CurrentValue["ShiftKey"],
                    y = MousePosition["GraphicsImageScaled"][[2]]-ref[[2]];
                    If[y>0, range=(range-ref2)*(z-y)+ref2,(*zoom in*)
                        If[y<0, range=(range-ref2)/(z+y)+ref2]];,(*zoom out*)
                    True,
                        (range=range0+(ref-MousePosition["GraphicsImageScaled"])(range0[[All,2]]-range0[[All,1]]));
                ],
            "MouseClicked" :> Which[ 
                CurrentValue["ControlKey"], range={{0,xaspect},{0,1}},(*Back to start*)
                CurrentValue["ShiftKey"],(*zoom out*)
                    range=(range-MousePosition["Graphics"])/fac+MousePosition["Graphics"];,
                True,(*zoom in*)
                    range=(range-MousePosition["Graphics"])*fac+MousePosition["Graphics"];
                ]},Method->"Preemptive"]
        ]
```

Applying the above function to an `Image` gives you both click-and-drag panning and zoom.

**To zoom in:**

- Hold shift and drag up
- or just click anywhere

**To zoom out:**

- Hold shift and drag down
- or just shift click anywhere

[image]

However, the frontend starts grinding to a halt on large images:

[image]

Comment: Good job, just don't show the pixel value.

Comment: @yode I can try to add the pixel values if this basic zoom functionally if working for you

Comment: Yes, it is a good solution..